# Routing not finding my web api

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying trying to call my web api.

This is the api controller:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Customer/Get/{CompanyRef}")]
    public IEnumerable<Services.Customer> Get(Guid CompanyRef)
    {
       return customerRepository.Get(CompanyRef);
    }
}
```

This is my client (c#desktop)

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("myuri");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri + route + "?CompanyRef=" + new Guid());
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 }
```

the uri call translates to:

```
http://myuri/api/Customer/Get?CompanyRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

the error I get is 'not found'?

Comment: Where's "api" defined?

Comment: without seeing your webapi config, the uri seems to be like: http://myuri/api/Customer/Get/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: @BigDaddy Hi, I have added the class name/path. It is a MVC5 webapp. isthat what you mean?

Comment: You need to make sure that your Web API routing is prefixed with "/api".  If not, your MVC call will fail.

Comment: shall give that a go :)

Comment: @BigDaddy I changed it to [Route("api/Customer/Get/{CompanyRef}")]

Comment: but the error was: No action was found on the controller 'Customer' that matches the request.

Comment: Does your request include a GET?

Comment: restarted IIS and the fix Timothy suggested makes it all now work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is actually completely in the wrong when it comes to OP's code and question. That is ASP.net WEB API v1.x way of doing the routing and OP is right in his comment that it is useless when using attributes.

[v2+ of Web API required]
For Attributes to work and the routes to be registered, you need to add the following code in your WebApiConfig.cs Route(config) method:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

That will parse all your `[RoutePrefix("..")]` and `[Route("..")]` and create your API's routing. It is a best practice to use `[RoutePrefix("..")]` to define the general path of the API in order to reach your controller & then map your different methods using the `[Route("..")]` & http verb attribute such as `[HttpGet]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your web api must have the following in your WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{CompanyRef}",
            defaults: new { CompanyRef= RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It appears from the branching you are getting that you don't have the input parameter in the branch as an optional parameter.  I changed the normal value from id to CompanyRef, but I think id would likely work as well.

Comment: Made no difference. Besides. I thought the whole point of using a [Route] tag is to avoid webapiconfig?

Comment: If you are using a web api controller class object, you must have the webapiconfig section in your code.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming that. I did have it in my api config file but it made no difference

Comment: Must have been something wrong with my Publish. Restarted IIS and republished and now it works. thanks

Comment: I have found that I have to kill anything in localhost if I change something significant.  It has a memory, and usually not what I want it to remember.